# Add background image on NetBeans Visual Library Tutorial

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, background

I'm doing a tutorial and would add a background image. I've tried to do this:

```
public void run() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("VisLibDemo");
    try{
         frame.setContentPane(new JLabel( new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/RPR1BRG/Pictures/Brg800.jpg")))));
    }catch(IOException e){
         System.out.println("Error");
    }
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 400));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setContentPane(new VisLibDemo());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

However I am not getting.

Or not showing the background image, or when it appears is on top and the rest will not appear.

This is what I have:

[image]

And I wanted to add image to background...

I do this:

```
  public void run() {
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(
        getClass().getResource("/Images/Brg800.jpg"));
        JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
        label.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("VisLibDemo");
        //frame.add(new VisLibDemo());
        frame.setContentPane(label);
        VisLibDemo demo = new VisLibDemo(); 
        demo.setOpaque(false); frame.add(demo);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

But I can only see a little  bit of the background image ("/Images/Brg800.jpg")

[image]

Sorry for the bad explanation. But I need some help!

Can help me Please!!

Answer (score 1):

Set the layout to the `JLabel`

```
JLabel label = new JLabel( new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/RPR1BRG/Pictures/Brg800.jpg")))));
label.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
frame.setContentPane(label);
```

---

**Side Notes**

When dealing with images that will be embedded into your program, you will want to load by **resource** and not by `File` which will not work on other systems beside the one you are developing on. To load by resource use

```
getClass().getResource("/path/to/image.png");
```

Your image should be in your `src` somewhere, where it will be built into the class path. So with this file structure

```
ProjectRoot
         src
            Pictures
                  Brg800.jpg
```

you would use this

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Pictures/Brg800.jpg"));
JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
label.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
frame.setContentPane(label);
```

See more at the link at the bottom of [**embedded resources**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) tag wiki

---

Here's an example of all the above fore-mentioned

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ASimpleExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(
                        getClass().getResource("/images/stackoverflow5.png"));
                JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
                label.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

                JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
                panel.setOpaque(false);
                panel.add(new JButton("Button"));

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setContentPane(label);
                frame.add(panel);
                frame.setSize(300, 300);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Is very explicit. 
But when I adapt the code did you say on mine, the image overlap the rest.  I don't know how to solve this...

Comment: set the label as the content pane, but also set the layout of the label to `BorderLayout`. Then you can just add component to the frame as you normally would.

Comment: I tried this: 
public void run() {
                ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(
                getClass().getResource("/Images/Brg800.jpg"));
                JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
                label.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("VisLibDemo");
                frame.setContentPane(label);
                frame.setSize(300, 300);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                frame.setVisible(true);
              }
But the image Brg800.jpg overlap

Comment: Sorry how was the response :S

Comment: Overlaps what? You don't add anything else to the frame for it to overlap anything.

Comment: Your `new VisLibDemo()`, **Don't** set it as the content pane. Just **`add()`** to the frame. `frame.add(new VisLibDemo());`

Comment: You probably need to set the `new VisLibDemo()` to `setOpaque(false)` so you can see the background image. So you need to `VisLibDemo demo = new VisLibDemo(); demo.setOpaque(false); frame.add(demo);`

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I tried what you said and I adapted my doubt upon. Now i can see a litle bit of background image on the left side...

Comment: The problem is most likely in the `VisLibDemo`. If you are using other `JPanels` inside the `VisLibDemo` `JPanel` you need to set all those opaque to false also.

Comment: You need to post a complete runnable example for more help. It is only guessing without it.

Comment: I posted a picture with what is happening!!
I hope it helps to understand my difficulty.