# Matisse properly setting image to panel

Tags: java, image, swing, netbeans, matisse

I got a problem with NetBeans resource managing while setting images to pannel:

This is my not working code:

```
try {
    BufferedImage myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("images/3D.jpg"));
    JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myPicture));
    pnlMain.add(picLabel); //the main and only pannel made by matisse is called pnlMain
} catch (IOException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Cannot set image");
}
```

The folder called "images" is in the MAIN project folder. There are several folders: build, nbproject, src and "images".
The problem I have is that the program runs but it doesnt set the image...

Someone suggested me to make another class in different package with this code:

```
public class PanelImage extends JPanel{
private Image imag;

public PanelImage(Image img){
    if(imagen != null){
        this.imagen = img;
    }
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(img, 0,0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
    setOpaque(false);
    super.paint(g);
}
}
```

But i cant find a proper way of implementing it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For your `ImagePanel` class**

1. `super.paint[Component]` *before* all the other stuff.
2. Don't override `paint` but instead `paintComponent`
3. Don't set properties in `paintComponent` method ie `setOpaque()`. Beside, `JPanel` is opaque by default
4. Override `getPreferredSize()` for painting on panels

**For loadng images**

Make a habit of not reading images from the file system, unless the application is specific to *only* your machine.

Instead read from the class path and make the image a resource by packaging it into the class path

1. Change your file structure

   ```
   ProjectRoot
            src
               images
                    3D.jpg
   ```
2. Read from class path. Use `ImageIO` to make sure your path is correct. If it's invalid, an exception will be thrown

   ```
   URL url = getClass().getResource("/images/3D.jpg"); 
   Image image = ImageIO.read(url);
   ```

**For Netbeans GUI Builder**

You can set the label icon using the design tool

1. Select your label from the navigator or the design view.
2. Go to the properties window in the right and find the property `icon`
3. click the ellipses button to the right of the property and a dialog will appear.
4. Find your image and select OK (make sure your image is in a package in the src)

---

See [related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22146266/2587435) and [maybe related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22214485/2587435)